# Hibernate one-to-one annotation exception

Tags: hibernate, annotations, one-to-one

I need some basic help with setting up a one-to-one mapping and query. I know this should be all over the internet, but I could not find a good explanation/example

2 Tables:

place and place_info
place has a primary key called place_id
place_info has a foreign key called place_id and it references the place_id in the place table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="place")
public class Place 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="place_id", nullable=false)
    private int placeId;

    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="category", nullable=false)
    private String category;

    @Column(name="submit_date", nullable=false)
    private Date submitDate;

    @Column(name="user")
    private String user;

@Entity
@Table(name="place_info")
public class PlaceInfo 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="place_info_id")
    private int placeInfoId;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name="hours")
    private String hours;

    @Column(name="submit_date", nullable=false)
    private Date submitDate;

    @Column(name="user")
    private String user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="place_id", referencedColumnName="place_id")
    private Place place;


public List<PlaceInfo> findPlaceInfo(Criteria criteria) {

        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("select pI, p.name from PlaceInfo pI");

        string.append(" inner join Place p p.placeId");
        if(criteria.getId()!=null)
            string.append(" where p.placeId = :id");

        Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(string.toString());

        if(criteria.getId()!=null)
            query.setParameter("id", criteria.getId());

        List<PlaceInfo> placeInfo = query.list();

        return placeInfo;
    }


Jan 29, 2013 10:23:03 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:87: unexpected token: p
Jan 29, 2013 10:23:03 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:87: unexpected token: p
line 1:87: unexpected token: p
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromJoin(HqlBaseParser.java:1693)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1348)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1054)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:700)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:294)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:157)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:219)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:197)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1732)
at com.collegecellar.repository.search.impl.SearchQueryRepositoryImpl.findPlaceInfo(SearchQueryRepositoryImpl.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy14.findPlaceInfo(Unknown Source)
at com.collegecellar.service.search.impl.SearchQueryServiceImpl.findPlaceInfo(SearchQueryServiceImpl.java:33)
at com.collegecellar.managedbean.review.ReviewBean.findPlaceInfo(ReviewBean.java:50)
at com.collegecellar.managedbean.review.ReviewBean.getSelectedPlace(ReviewBean.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:730)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:729)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:581)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:355)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:581)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:220)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:192)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:74)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jan 29, 2013 10:23:03 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/reviews.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /reviews.xhtml @13,63 value="#{reviewBean.selectedPlace}": Error reading 'selectedPlace' on type com.collegecellar.managedbean.review.ReviewBean
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:730)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:729)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:581)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:355)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:581)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:220)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:192)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:74)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: p near line 1, column 87 [select pI, p.name from com.collegecellar.domain.place.PlaceInfo pI inner join Place p p.placeId where p.placeId = :id]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:219)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:197)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1732)
at com.collegecellar.repository.search.impl.SearchQueryRepositoryImpl.findPlaceInfo(SearchQueryRepositoryImpl.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy14.findPlaceInfo(Unknown Source)
at com.collegecellar.service.search.impl.SearchQueryServiceImpl.findPlaceInfo(SearchQueryServiceImpl.java:33)
at com.collegecellar.managedbean.review.ReviewBean.findPlaceInfo(ReviewBean.java:50)
at com.collegecellar.managedbean.review.ReviewBean.getSelectedPlace(ReviewBean.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
... 39 more
Jan 29, 2013 10:23:04 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:87: unexpected token: p
Jan 29, 2013 10:23:04 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:87: unexpected token: p
line 1:87: unexpected token: p
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromJoin(HqlBaseParser.java:1693)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1348)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1054)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:700)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:294)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:157)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:219)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:197)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1732)
at com.collegecellar.repository.search.impl.SearchQueryRepositoryImpl.findPlaceInfo(SearchQueryRepositoryImpl.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy14.findPlaceInfo(Unknown Source)
at com.collegecellar.service.search.impl.SearchQueryServiceImpl.findPlaceInfo(SearchQueryServiceImpl.java:33)
at com.collegecellar.managedbean.review.ReviewBean.findPlaceInfo(ReviewBean.java:50)
at com.collegecellar.managedbean.review.ReviewBean.getSelectedPlace(ReviewBean.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:730)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:729)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeAttributes(DevTools.java:375)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeStart(DevTools.java:424)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeComponent(DevTools.java:245)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeComponent(DevTools.java:264)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeComponent(DevTools.java:264)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeComponent(DevTools.java:264)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.debugHtml(DevTools.java:128)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.renderHtmlErrorPage(RenderKitUtils.java:1207)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:139)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line provokes the error:

```
string.append(" inner join Place p p.placeId");
```

Correct is

```
string.append(" inner join pI.place p");
```

You don't need to mention the name of the join column. It already is done in the annotation. And then for the inner join you don't give the class but the member name.

Nevertheless, this does not produce a list of PlaceInfo, because you also select p.name (which is superfluous).

The correct code is

```
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("from PlaceInfo pI");
    string.append(" inner join pI.place");
    if(criteria.getId()!=null)
        string.append(" where pI.place.placeId = :id");
```

When you need the name of the place then you reference it like

```
placeInfo.get(i).place.name
```

(In your code placeInfo is a list of PlaceInfo instances, which is confusing. You'd better name it placeInfoList and use the name placeInfo only for single instances of PlaceInfo.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was so confused before, there were so many different ways people were telling me to annotate. I wasn't sure if my problem was with the annotations or query. It all works, thank you again!!